# How to set a background image in Xcode using swift according the schema?

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, swift3

I have 3 schemas (dev, hom and prod) and for each schema I'd like to set a background image.

I know how to do programmatically, I'd like to know if have some way more elegant?

Answer (score 2):

One option to configure background assert using scheme, is to use '*Environment Variables*'.

Scheme Settings:

[image]

For each scheme in your project create a environmental variable '*BackgroundImage*' and have assert name as value.

To configure your UIImageView you can try using *ProcessInfo* class.

```
var backgroundAssert = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["BackgroundImage"] // Get Assert Name 
UIImage(named:backgroundAssert) // Get UIImage from assert name
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can create plist file Called it  schemas  have three main category

dev, home and prod

or you can use Enum  for that without plist

then create Class , SchemasManager  that can manage all this process
here is an example for ThemeManager.swift

https://gist.github.com/durul/16ed8ab13b2179f0bc1d87c4ca9880d1